# override RSPAMD_URIBL for single domain?

Tags: rspamd

I am using rspamd (under mailcow-dockerized)

I disagree with a domain RSPAMD_URIBL marks as spam.

Is there a way for me to override this domain only?

I am in control of a DNS-server.

Answer (score 0):

As documented, and as configured in *modules.d/rbl.conf*, you should add required domain into *local.d/maps.d/surbl-whitelist.inc.local* file (create file if it not exists).